# Minimize total area using K rectangles in less than O(N^4)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an increasing sequence of N numbers (up to T), we can use at most K rectangles (placed starting at position 0) such as for the i-th value v in the sequence, exists a rectangle in positions [v, T) with height at least i + 1.

Total area of rectangles should be the minimum that satisfies what mentioned above.

Example: given the sequence [0, 3, 4], T = 5 and K = 2 we can use:

- a rectangle from 0 to 2 with height 1 (thus having an area of 3)
- a rectangle from 3 to 4 with height 3 (thus having an area of 6).

Using at most 2 rectangles, we cannot get a total area smaller than 9.

This problem can be solved using DP.

```
int dp[MAXK+1][MAXN][MAXN];
int sequence[MAXN];
int filldp(int cur_idx, int cur_value, int cur_K) {
    int res = dp[cur_K][cur_idx][cur_value];
    if (res != -1) return res;

    res = INF;
    if (cur_idx == N - 1 && cur_value >= N)
        res = min(res, (T - seq[cur_idx]) * cur_value);
    else {
        if (cur_idx < N - 1 && cur_value >= cur_idx + 1) {
            int cur_cost = (seq[cur_idx + 1] - seq[cur_idx]) * cur_value;
            res = min(res, cur_cost + filldp(cur_idx + 1, cur_value, cur_K);
        }

        // Try every possible height for a rectangle
        if (cur_K < K)
            for (int new_value = cur_value + 1; cur_value <= N; new_value++)
                res = min(res, filldp(cur_idx, new_value, cur_K + 1));
    }
    dp[cur_K][cur_idx][cur_value] = res;
    return res;
}
```

Unsurprisingly, this DP approach is not really fast probably due to the `for` cycle. However, as far as I can understand, this code should not do more than MAXK * MAXN * MAXN significative calls (i.e., not more that every cell in `dp`). MAXK and MAXN are both 200, so `dp` has 8 millions of cells, which is not too much.

Am I missing anything?

UPDATE: As pointed out by Saeed Amiri (thank you!), the code makes N^2*K significative calls, but each one is O(N). The whole algorithm is then O(N^3*K) = O(N^4).

Can we do better?

Comment: the question can be solved by DP but your code is brute force.. consider sorting the rectangles by height/width, look at the solution for the classic "Counting Change" problem and work from there.

Comment: What is the maximum value of T? Your algorithm is in fact TxN^3

Comment: @SaeedAmiri MAXT is 3600, but I don't get why is TN^3 instead of N^3.

Comment: There is a Matrix which is NxNxT, in fact the cur_value, in your procedure ranges from 1..T. On the other hand in order to fill this matrix, in the procedure you have O(N)  for the loop so it is O(Nx sizeof_matrix).

Comment: `cur_value` ranges in 0...N, as it is the height of rectangles and no height more than N makes sense.

Comment: Then I don't know then why MAXT should be 3600. But anyway, then it is N^4, not N^3.

Comment: In the question you wrote: "Given an increasing sequence of N numbers (up to T),", so the maximum value is T not N. And then later you wrote: "exists a rectangle in positions [v, T)", that means your positions range is within 1..T not 1..N, hence the total running time should be TxN^3. Otherwise let me know what does T is doing at all?!

Comment: Both statements are correct. But I loop over the array `sequence`, which has a length of N. T is only used at the end.

However you're right, N^3 calls but they are O(N) each, so the total is O(N^4) which is too large.

Comment: Quick tip for checking memoization: print a character every time you get a match, to see if you're actually recalling anything or just storing results that are never read.

Comment: @lucach, that's what I already said two comments above. But even N^4 for N=200 is not bad and if it doesn't end within a second the problem is sth else.

Comment: It's not too bad, but takes a couple of seconds in worst cases. Updated question text.